# Visualize Elasticsearch index size in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

is it possible to show the size (physical size, e.g. MB) of one or more ES indices in Kibana?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Kibana only:**

It's not possible out of the box to view the disk-size of indices in Kibana.

Use the [cat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) command to know how big your indices are (thats even possible without any Kibana).
If you need to view that data in Kibana index the output from the cat command to a dedicated Elasticsearch index and analyse it then in Kibana.

---

**If other plugins/tools then Kibana are acceptable, read the following:**

Check the Elasticsearch [community plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/management.html). The [Head-Plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) (which I would recommand to you) gives you the info you want in addition to many other infos, like stats about your Shards, Nodes, etc...

Alternatively you could use the commerical Marvel Plugin from Elastic. I have never used it before, but it should be capeable of what you want, and much more. But Marvel is likely an overkill for what you want - so I wouldn't recommand that in the first place.

---

Comment: I used head before (Kopf is also pretty nice), but I would like to display this size over time. I used to use Marvel (or try it at least), and I think it's even suplying this functionality (size over time), but the commercial license is a no-go.
So I guess I'lll have to go with creating a seperate index.
Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 0):

Although not a plugin of Kibana, cerebro is the official replacement of Kopf and runs as a standalone web server that can connect remotely to ElasticSearch instances. The UI is very informational and functional.

https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro